# How to split txt file into two colums in array Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, split

I have .txt file consist of "name" and "value" (John Anderson, 54) and I woud like to split it by "," into 2 columns array. I did it with a hash but I have no idea how to do it with array.
This is how I did it with hash.

```
def initialize(file)
  @file_data ={|h,k|}
  File.open(file) do |file|
    file.each_line do |line|
      line_data = line.split(",")
      @file_data[line_data[0]]= line_data[1].to_i
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just use CSV module. Documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? [[name1, age1], [name2, age2]... ]?

Comment: Yes I except [[name1, age1], [name2, age2]... ]

Comment: You need to show sample input and the expected output. Don't make us guess.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Ruby's [`CSV`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html) class. The default column separator is `,` so this should work:

```
require 'csv'

def initialize(file)
  @file_data = CSV.read(file)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The CSV module is probably the way to go, or perhaps something like:

```
def read_data(file)
  File.read(file).lines.map{|line| line.chomp.split(', ')}
end

my_array_of_values = read_data(path_to_file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did that worked.

require 'CSV'

```
column0=[]
column1=[]
CSV.foreach("test.txt") do |row|
    column0 << row[0]
    column1 << row[1]
    end

print column1
print column0
```